# Correctly Deal With Byte Alignment Issues -- Between 16 Bit Embeded System and 32 Bit Desktop via UDP

Tags: c++, c, casting, embedded

The application I am working on receives C style structs from an embed system whose code was generated to target a 16 bit processor. The application which speaks with the embedded system is built with either a 32 bit gcc compiler, or a 32 bit MSVC c++ compiler. The communication between the application and the embedded system takes place via UDP packets over ethernet or modem.

The payload within the UDP packets consist of various different C style structs. On the application side a C++ style `reinterpret_cast` is capable of taking the unsigned byte array and casting it into the appropriate struct.

However, I run into problems with `reinterpret_cast` when the struct contains enumerated values. The 16 bit Watcom compiler will treat enumerated values as an uint8_t type. However, on the application side the enumerated values are treated as 32 bit values. When I receive a packet with enumerated values in it the data gets garbled because the size of the struct on the application side is larger the struct on the embedded side.

The solution to this problem, so far, has been to change the enumerated type within the struct on the application side to an uint8_t. However, this is not an optimal solution because we can no longer use the member as an enumerated type.

What I am looking for is a solution which will allow me to use a simple cast operation without having to tamper with the struct definition in the source on the application side. By doing so, I can use the struct as is in the upper layers of my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, correctly deal with the issue is proper serialization and deserialization.

But it doesn't mean we can't try some hacks.

Option 1:
If you particular compiler support packing the enum (in my case gcc 4.7 in windows), this might work:

```
typedef enum { VALUE_1 = 1, VALUE_2, VALUE_3 }__attribute__ ((__packed__)) TheRealEnum;
```

Option 2:

If your particular compiler supports class sizes of < 4 bytes, you can use a *HackedEnum* class which uses operator overloading for the conversion (note the gcc **attribute** you might not want it):

```
class HackedEnum
{
private:
    uint8_t evalue;
public:
    void operator=(const TheRealEnum v) { evalue = v; };
    operator TheRealEnum() { return (TheRealEnum)evalue; };
}__attribute__((packed));
```

You would replace **TheRealEnum** in your structures for **HackedEnum**, but you still continue using it as TheRealEnum.

A full example to see it working:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stddef.h>

using namespace std;

#pragma pack(push, 1)

typedef enum { VALUE_1 = 1, VALUE_2, VALUE_3 } TheRealEnum;

typedef struct
{
    uint16_t v1;
    uint8_t enumValue;
    uint16_t v2;
}__attribute__((packed)) ShortStruct;

typedef struct
{
    uint16_t v1;
    TheRealEnum enumValue;
    uint16_t v2;
}__attribute__((packed)) LongStruct;

class HackedEnum
{
private:
    uint8_t evalue;
public:
    void operator=(const TheRealEnum v) { evalue = v; };
    operator TheRealEnum() { return (TheRealEnum)evalue; };
}__attribute__((packed));

typedef struct
{
    uint16_t v1;
    HackedEnum enumValue;
    uint16_t v2;
}__attribute__((packed)) HackedStruct;

#pragma pop()

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cout << "Sizes: " << endl
         << "TheRealEnum: " << sizeof(TheRealEnum) << endl
         << "ShortStruct: " << sizeof(ShortStruct) << endl
         << "LongStruct: " << sizeof(LongStruct) << endl
         << "HackedStruct: " << sizeof(HackedStruct) << endl;

    ShortStruct ss;
    cout << "address of ss: " << &ss <<  " size " << sizeof(ss) <<endl
         << "address of ss.v1: " << (void*)&ss.v1 << endl
         << "address of ss.ev: " << (void*)&ss.enumValue << endl
         << "address of ss.v2: " << (void*)&ss.v2 << endl;

    LongStruct ls;
    cout << "address of ls: " << &ls <<  " size " << sizeof(ls) <<endl
         << "address of ls.v1: " << (void*)&ls.v1 << endl
         << "address of ls.ev: " << (void*)&ls.enumValue << endl
         << "address of ls.v2: " << (void*)&ls.v2 << endl;

    HackedStruct hs;
    cout << "address of hs: " << &hs <<  " size " << sizeof(hs) <<endl
         << "address of hs.v1: " << (void*)&hs.v1 << endl
         << "address of hs.ev: " << (void*)&hs.enumValue << endl
         << "address of hs.v2: " << (void*)&hs.v2 << endl;


    uint8_t buffer[512] = {0};

    ShortStruct * short_ptr = (ShortStruct*)buffer;
    LongStruct * long_ptr = (LongStruct*)buffer;
    HackedStruct * hacked_ptr = (HackedStruct*)buffer;

    short_ptr->v1 = 1;
    short_ptr->enumValue = VALUE_2;
    short_ptr->v2 = 3;

    cout << "Values of short: " << endl
            << "v1 = " << short_ptr->v1 << endl
            << "ev = " << (int)short_ptr->enumValue << endl
            << "v2 = " << short_ptr->v2 << endl;

    cout << "Values of long: " << endl
            << "v1 = " << long_ptr->v1 << endl
            << "ev = " << long_ptr->enumValue << endl
            << "v2 = " << long_ptr->v2 << endl;

    cout << "Values of hacked: " << endl
            << "v1 = " << hacked_ptr->v1 << endl
            << "ev = " << hacked_ptr->enumValue << endl
            << "v2 = " << hacked_ptr->v2 << endl;



    HackedStruct hs1, hs2;

    // hs1.enumValue = 1; // error, the value is not the wanted enum

    hs1.enumValue = VALUE_1;
    int a = hs1.enumValue;
    TheRealEnum b = hs1.enumValue;
    hs2.enumValue = hs1.enumValue;

    return 0;
}
```

The output on my particular system is:

```
Sizes:
TheRealEnum: 4
ShortStruct: 5
LongStruct: 8
HackedStruct: 5
address of ss: 0x22ff17 size 5
address of ss.v1: 0x22ff17
address of ss.ev: 0x22ff19
address of ss.v2: 0x22ff1a
address of ls: 0x22ff0f size 8
address of ls.v1: 0x22ff0f
address of ls.ev: 0x22ff11
address of ls.v2: 0x22ff15
address of hs: 0x22ff0a size 5
address of hs.v1: 0x22ff0a
address of hs.ev: 0x22ff0c
address of hs.v2: 0x22ff0d
Values of short:
v1 = 1
ev = 2
v2 = 3
Values of long:
v1 = 1
ev = 770
v2 = 0
Values of hacked:
v1 = 1
ev = 2
v2 = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

> On the application side a C++ style reinterpret_cast is capable of taking the unsigned byte array and casting it into the appropriate struct.

The layout of structs is not required to be the same between different implementations. Using reinterpret_cast in this way is not appropriate.

> The 16 bit Watcom compiler will treat enumerated values as an uint8_t type. However, on the application side the enumerated values are treated as 32 bit values.

The underlying type of an enum is chosen by the implementation, and is chosen in an implementation defined manner.

This is just one of the many potential differences between implementations that can cause problems with your reinterpret_cast. There are also actual alignment issues if you're not careful, where the data in the received buffer isn't appropriately aligned for the types (e.g., an integer that requires four byte alignment ends up one byte off) which can cause crashes or poor performance. Padding might be different between platforms, fundamental types might have different sizes, endianess can differ, etc.

> What I am looking for is a solution which will allow me to use a simple cast operation without having to tamper with the struct definition in the source on the application side. By doing so, I can use the struct as is in the upper layers of my application.

C++11 introduces a new enum syntax that allows you to specify the underlying type. Or you can replace your enums with integral types along with a bunch of predefined constants with manually declared values. This only fixes the problem you're asking about and not any of the other ones you have.

What you should really do is proper serialization and deserialization.

Comment: I am looking at the libstdc++ code provided by the GNU website, however my greps do not return the definition of reinterpret cast. Could you provide me the source or how to get it so I can see why byte alignment might not hold 100% of the time?

Comment: reinterpret_cast is not a function that has source code, it only looks like a template function. In fact it is a built-in language feature implemented by the compiler, and it does different things based on the types you provide it with. If you want to see exactly what it does you should read its definition in the C++ standard. Find the standard [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (5.1 MiB pdf) and go to section 5.2.10.

Comment: As for what problem reinterpret_cast can cause with alignment: Different types can have different alignment requirements. The compiler ensures that objects are stored at locations appropriate for their type, but with reinterpet_cast you can produce pointers that are not correctly aligned (such a cast triggers UB). Then when you try to use that pointer, depending on the platform, you can get a bus error or accessing the memory may take longer than normal.

Answer (score 0):

Put your enumerated type inside of a union with a 32-bit number:

```
union
{
  Enumerated val;
  uint32_t valAsUint32;
};
```

This would make the embedded side have it expanded to 32-bit. Should work as long as both platforms are little-endian and the structs are zero-filled initially. This would change wire format, though.

Comment: Don't have control over embeded side. And I am sure that the embeded programers would not like to have more memory taken up by larger enumerations.

Answer (score 0):

If by "simple cast operation" you mean something that's expressed in the source code, rather than something that's necessarily zero-copy, then you can write two versions of the struct -- one with enums, one with uint8_ts, and a constructor for one from the other that copies it element-by-element to repack it.  Then you can use an ordinary type-cast in the rest of the code.  Since the data sizes are fundamentally different (unless you use the C++11 features mentioned in another answer), you can't do this without copying things to repack them.

However, if you don't mind some small changes to the struct definition on the application side, there are a couple of options that don't involve dealing with bare uint8_t values.  You could use aaronps's answer of a class that is the size of a uint8_t (assuming that's possible with your compiler) and implicitly converts to and from an enum.  Alternately, you could store the values as uint8_ts and write some accessor methods for your enum values that take the uint8_t data in the struct and convert it to an enum before returning it.